# Can i set custom page and margins while generating PDF ? I tried but no luck app script

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-apps-script

I am working on a project where i want to generate a pdf of size 52 mm x 25 mm. I use the following code to generate pdf and works fine except the page sizes.

```
    function CreaPDF() {
  //The function prints an invoice to PDF. First it copies spreadsheet to a new document.
  //Deletes all sheet except the one to print. Saves it to PDF. 
  //It overwrites any existing doc with same name.

  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();          
  var sheetName = "Factura";
  var folderID = getParentFolder(); // Folder id to save in a folder.
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID); 
  var numf = sourceSpreadsheet.getRangeByName("NumeroFactura").getValue();
  var anof = numf.split("/",2);   // Seeks number and year -> filename 

  var pdfName = anof[1] +"_Factura_" + anof[0]+ "_Dra_Salazar"; // Nombre del documento;

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Creando PDF');

  // export url
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/'+sourceSpreadsheet.getId()+'/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
  + '&size=A4'                           // paper size legal / letter / A4
  + '&portrait=true'                     // orientation, false for landscape
  + '&fitw=false'                        // fit to page width, false for actual size
  + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
  + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
  + '&fzr=false'                         // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
  + '&gid='+sourceSheet.getSheetId();    // the sheet's Id

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

  // request export url
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
    }
  });

  var theBlob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName+'.pdf');

  // delete pdf if already exists
  var files = folder.getFilesByName(pdfName);
  while (files.hasNext())
  {
    files.next().setTrashed(true);
  }

  // create pdf
  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);

  return true;
}
```

What i want is to set a custom page size in the link and custom margins. I want to send this pdf to Dymo Label printing automatically.

Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: So what page size do you get? Does it work if you try a larger size?

Comment: Yes its working perfectly with standard large page sizes but i want to generate a PDF of 52 mm x 25 mm size with 0.1 margins for label printing .

Comment: If there is an alternate way to generate an image with no margins than it will be also fine.

Comment: Before PDF 1.6, the minimum size of a page was 1" x 1" – 25.4 x 25.4 mm. Try your code with a height of 25.4 mm – if that works, your library is hardcoded to not allow smaller sizes.

Comment: I just know another way to generate PDF from google sheet :    var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();

Comment: But it also not works. Can you suggest a custom code that allow me to generate a pdf with custom size and margins. Thank you for your help.